# How ro populate/ store NetworkImage widgets in a list or an array using the data stored in firestore cloud database in flutter in a function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I am using a plugin called carousel pro in flutter which needs a **list** of NetworkImage in order to display the images in carousel and I am not able to make a function which can populate NetworkImage from the following firestore cloud db :-

[image]

I want to make a list of NetworkImage using the urls stored in bannerUrl
Please help me to address this issue

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have come up with a function in order to resolve the issue.

Here it is :-

```
bool imagesFilled = false;
List<NetworkImage> bannerImages = [];

Future getBanners() async {

    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("banners").getDocuments();
    int len = await qn.documents.asMap().length;
    NetworkImage a;
    if(!imagesFilled){
      for (int i = 0;i< len; i++){
        a = NetworkImage(qn.documents.asMap()[i].data['bannerUrl']);
        bannerImages.add(a);
      }
      imagesFilled = true;
    }
    return qn.documents.asMap();
  }
```

And Boom! you will get all the images in list named **bannerImages**